# document.body vs Document.prototype.body

Tags: javascript, prototype

Since

```
document.__proto__.__proto__===Document.prototype
```

returns true and since

```
Document.prototype.hasOwnProperty('body')
```

also returns true

could someone explain to me why **document.body** and **Document.prototype.body** are not the same thing? Moreover, why ***Document.prototype.body*** inside Chrome developer tools results to

```
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation(…)
(anonymous function) @ VM6098:2
InjectedScript._evaluateOn @ VM3911:904
InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap @ VM3911:837
InjectedScript.evaluate @ VM3911:693
```

whereas ***document.body*** results to

```
<body...>...</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Document.prototype` is the type (prototype..) of `document.__proto__`, but it doesn't mean it's the same object. Through inheritance, properties that are not found as properties of an object are looked up in it's prototype chain. In the case of `document.body`, that comes from `Document.prototype.body`, so let's look at that property:

```js
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Document.prototype, 'body'))
```

As can be seen, the `body` property has a *getter* method defined, and it isn't a simple primitive value. That already gives us hint why `Document.prototype.body` might fail - it needs some instance to operate on.

In fact we can call this method with a `this` of our choosing, our `document` instance:

```js
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Document.prototype, 'body').get.call(document))
```

And now it's clear to see what the difference is and why it behaves differently.